# How to modify the Powershell Calculated Property with If Else statement for SMTPAddresses?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, azure-powershell, powershell-remoting, windows-scripting

I am wanting to modify the Powershell to list users from Azure AD to display the information correctly in the SMTP Address Column.

The below script is correct, I just need to make some changes like below if possible:

- If the UserPrincipalName value contains Company1.onmicrosoft.com, then SMTP Address column should show everything as it is, do not process anything.
- If the UserPrincipalName value does NOT contain Company1.onmicrosoft.com, then SMTP Address column should NOT display the *@Company1.mail.onmicrosoft.com or *@Company1.onmicrosoft.com, so only the normal SMTP protocol address.
- The Licenses column should NOT display the prefix Company1:EnterpriseE1, but just EnterpriseE1.

So far I can only display the ProxyAddresses with SMTP like:

```
@{Label = 'SMTP Address'; Expression = { ($_.proxyAddresses | Where-Object { $_ -like "*smtp*" }) -replace 'smtp:' -join ';' } }
```

Here it is my full script:

```
#Import Module
If (!(Get-Module "*MSOnline*")) {Import-Module MSOnline}
If (!(Get-Module "*Exchange*")) {Import-Module $((Get-ChildItem -Path $($env:LOCALAPPDATA + "\Apps\2.0\") -Filter Microsoft.Exchange.Management.ExoPowershellModule.dll -Recurse).FullName | ?{ $_ -notmatch "_none_" } | select -First 1)}

#Set admin UPN
$UPN = 'Global.Admin@domain.com'

#This connects to Azure Active Directory & Exchange Online
Connect-MsolService
$EXOSession = New-ExoPSSession -UserPrincipalName $UPN
Import-PSSession $EXOSession -DisableNameChecking -AllowClobber

$startsWith = @(
    'Test'
    'Sync_'
)

$endsWith = @(
    '365'
    '\$'
    'svc'
    'Sync'
    'user'
)

$pattern = '^({0})|({1})$' -f $($startsWith -join '|'), $($endsWith -join '|')

# Member Outputs for Microsoft.Online.Administration.User based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/get-msoluser?view=azureadps-1.0
$allUsers = @()
$allUsers = Get-MsolUser -All -EnabledFilter EnabledOnly | Where-Object {
        ($_.UserPrincipalName -notmatch $pattern) -and
        ($_.UserPrincipalName -notlike '*#EXT#*') -and
        ($_.DisplayName -notmatch 'Admin|Calendar|Room|Prod|Account|Fax|Team|Office|Test|User')
} | Select-Object FirstName, LastName, UserPrincipalName, @{Label = 'SMTP Address'; Expression = { ($_.proxyAddresses | Where-Object { $_ -like "*smtp*" }) -replace 'smtp:' -join ';' } }, AlternateEmailAddresses, UsageLocation, isLicensed, Licenses, PasswordNeverExpires, BlockCredential

$allUsers | Out-GridView
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by normal SMTP protocol address.

> If the UserPrincipalName value does NOT contain
> Company1.onmicrosoft.com, then SMTP Address column should NOT display
> the *@Company1.mail.onmicrosoft.com or *@Company1.onmicrosoft.com, so
> only the normal SMTP protocol address.

However, it's pretty straight forward to add logic to a calculated property.  Hopefully this example can give you the groundwork.

It can be a little messy so I like to park the Hash table expression definition in a separate variable to later reference in the `Select-Object` command:

...

```
$SMTPExpression = 
@{
    Label = 'SMTP Address'
    Expression = 
    {
        If( $_.UserPrincipalName -match 'company1,onmicrosoft.com$')
        {
            $_.ProxyAddresses.Where( { $_ -match '^smtp:' } ) -replace 'smtp:'
        }
        Else
        {
            # Add some value or expression here...
            $_.ProxyAddresses.Where( { $_ -match '^smtp:' } )
        }
    }
}

$allUsers = Get-MsolUser -All -EnabledFilter EnabledOnly | 
Where-Object {
    ($_.UserPrincipalName -notmatch $pattern) -and
    ($_.UserPrincipalName -notlike '*#EXT#*') -and
    ($_.DisplayName -notmatch 'Admin|Calendar|Room|Prod|Account|Fax|Team|Office|Test|User') } | 
Select-Object FirstName, LastName, UserPrincipalName, $SMTPExpression, AlternateEmailAddresses, UsageLocation, isLicensed, Licenses, PasswordNeverExpires, BlockCredential |


$allUsers | Out-GridView
```

I did change your where statement a little, again just trying to make it a little shorter and a couple of other minor things (slight reformat so I could work easier....).

I don't have an environment to test this in, but the strategy is solid.

Comment: Hi @Steven, thanks for the update. However, the result still contains smtp:First.Last@domain.com and the column content not showing fully hence there are result like smtp:First.Last@domain.com; smtp:First.Alias@domain.com; smtp:2nd.Lastalias@...

Comment: The idea is to remove the smtp: prefix, and just display First.Last@domain.com; First.Alias@domain.com; 2nd.LastAlias@domain.com; 3rdAlias@domain.com for all users with the UserPrincipalName NOT like UserPrincipalName -match 'company1.onmicrosoft.com'

Comment: OK, I finally got it working by using:
    @{Label = 'SMTP Address(es)'; 
        Expression = { 
            If (( $_.UserPrincipalName -match 'onmicrosoft.com$')) {
              ($_.proxyAddresses | Where-Object { ($_ -like 'SMTP*') -and ($_ -like '*onmicrosoft.com') }) -replace 'smtp:' -join ';'
            } Else {
                ($_.proxyAddresses | Where-Object { ($_ -like 'SMTP*') -and ($_ -notlike '*onmicrosoft.com') }) -replace 'smtp:' -join ';'
            }
        } 
    },

Comment: Glad to hear it's worked out.  I wasn't sure about replacing 'smtp:' in else block.  Arrays will always truncate their display in a table, that's why you had to join back to a string to get the display correct.